# Why Vue.js instance doesn't work in Firefox Extension Development?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firefox-addon

Manifest.json:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Vue",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Vue Test",

  "icons": {
    "96": "icons/icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon.png",
    "default_title": "Vue"
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(()=>{
    browser.tabs.create({url: 'index.html'})
       .then(()=>browser.tabs.executeScript({file: "index.js"}))
       .then(()=>browser.tabs.executeScript({file: "vue.js"}))
})
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Vue</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">{{msg}}</div>
    
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

vue.js: the vue.js itself downloaded from vue page

index.js:

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'hi'
  }
})
```

The problem: nothing is been rendered on screen. If I get the same index.html and open it directly on browser, it will render the message 'hi'. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `vue.js` and `index.js` aren't required to import again in the `index.html` file as it is already injected/executed from `background.js`.

Second, in `background.js`, `vue.js` should be executed first (For VueJS to be ready to initialize the main application later on) and we should actually wait until it is finished executing before proceeding on with `index.js`.

So, in conclusion, `background.js` should be something like this:

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(async ()=>{
   await browser.tabs.create({url: 'index.html'});
   await browser.tabs.executeScript({file: "vue.js"});
   await browser.tabs.executeScript({file: "index.js"});
});
```

And remove

```
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

from `index.html`

Comment: Still not working with changes. HTML shows only {{msg}} :(

Comment: Wait... it's working! After the changes and removing a function inside catch that I was using but it wasn't defined, everything worked. Thanks!